# Proper way to define and initialize Decimal in Managed C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, decimal

This seems like it should be really simple but I'm having trouble finding the answer online.

What's the proper way to define a Decimal variable and initialize it with constant value in C++/CLI?

In C# it would be:

```
decimal d = 1.1M;
```

In C++/CLI I've been doing:

```
Decimal d = (Decimal)1.1;
```

Which works for some numbers, but I suspect it's just converting from double.

I notice there's a constructor: `Decimal(int, int, int, bool, unsigned char)` but was hoping there's an easier way to deal with large specific numbers.

Comment: The C++/CLI compiler does not have additional literal types beyond those offered by C++.  An arbitrary workaround it is to initialize with 11 and divide by 10.

Comment: I guess if I used 64-bit numbers there should always be a power of 10 that works.  Although, it appears Int64.MaxValue is smaller than Decimal.MaxValue so this would only work for a certain range of values.  I was also thinking d = Decimal::Parse("1.1"); but efficiency likely wouldn't be good and the compiler won't check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed casting the number. You can, as mentioned, parse from a string or divide integers, or you may want to use the [BigRational](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782) data type. Independently of the option you choose you may create a utility method in a static class to do it so you don't have to repeat it all the time.

You can also suggest on the [VS UserVoice Site](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) to allow number sufixes like in C#.

Comment: Just `BigInteger` by itself really helps.  `(Decimal)(BigInteger(10000)*BigInteger(42))/(Decimal)((BigInteger(100)*BigInteger(100))` gets me pretty far...  Pardon for not accepting yet, I've got to think about your answer a bit.  I guess I should have RTM.

Comment: @ebyrob, take the time you want, I actually once had this problem, and just divided integers (as the `BigInteger`s in your example). I added the `BigRational` type as another way to do it, as the others were already in the comments. And I would post the suffix idea on UserVoice, but I posted a few and already used up my votes. Also, what do you mean by "should have RTM"?

Comment: RTM - read the manual.  BigInteger was there in .Net 4.0 all along, I just didn't even know about it.